# Generate Table grid with count of repeating items (JSON Data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table, sharepoint-online

I need to build a grid table of the following format using JSON data received from a Sharepoint Online REST API service.

Requirement example, data created between 22/05/2021 03:00Z to 23/05/2021 02:59Z should be counted and displayed under 23/05/2021.

JSON Sample

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadNumber": {},
                "Number": 21,
                "Created": "2021-05-21T14:47:55Z"
            },
            {
                "__metadNumber": {},
                "Number": 21,
                "Created": "2021-05-21T13:47:55Z"
            },
            {
                "__metadNumber": {},
                "Number": 28,
                "Created": "2021-05-22T14:48:44Z"
            }
        ],
        "__next": ""
    }
}
```

Desired Table format

| Number | 21/05/2021 | 22/05/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | (2) | (0) |
| 28 | (0) | (1) |

The following code is what I have for now. Issue is that, this does not populate a count in the corresponding cell.

```
    $(function(){
        var requestUri = "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=100&$select=*";
        $.ajax({url: requestUri, type: "GET", headers: {"accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"}, success: onSuccess,});

      function onSuccess(data) {
         var objItems = data.d.results;
         var tableContent;
         var tableRow;
         for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
             tableContent += '<td>' + moment(objItems[i].Created).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + '</td>';
             tableRow += '<tr><td>' + objItems[i].Number + '</td></tr>';
        }
       $('#Date').append(tableContent);
       $('#number').append(tableRow);
       }
    });  

<table id='dateNumber' class="table table-striped table-sm small">
   <tr>
      <td id="Date"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="number"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the exact output you're currently having please share here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following in your `onSuccess` function:

```js
var objItems = data.d.results;

var groups = [];
var dates = [];

objItems.forEach(function (item) {
  var number = item.Number;
  var date = moment(item.Created).format("DD/MM/YYYY");

  var group = groups[number] || [];
  var created = group[date] || 0;

  group[date] = created + 1;

  groups[number] = group;

  if (dates.indexOf(date) === -1) {
    dates.push(date);
  }
});

var tableRows = "<tr><td>Number</td>";

dates.forEach(function (date) {
  tableRows += "<td>" + date + "</td>";
});

tableRows += "</tr>";

groups.forEach(function (group, number) {
  tableRows += "<tr><td>" + number + "</td>";

  dates.forEach(function (date) {
    tableRows += "<td>" + (group[date] || 0) + "</td>";
  });

  tableRows += "</tr>";
});

// TODO: append the table rows to the table
```

This would produce the table rows (with the correct header row) with the desired format.

Example output for `tableRows`:

```html
<tr><td>Number</td><td>21/05/2021</td><td>22/05/2021</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>2</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>28</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr>
```

which would result in this table:
[Example output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W94nB.png)

Comment: Hi Matthias, appreciate the answer. I can confirm this works to count an item created between 00:00-23:59. Would it be possible to modify this to count entries created between 03:00-02:59? Kindly assist.

Comment: Hi @JacksonChristopher, to what date would the ones from 00:00 - 02:59 then count? If they would count to the date from before, you could simply subtract 3 hours from the date: `var date = new Date(item.Created); date.setHours(date.getHours() - 3);` (and then format it accordingly)

Comment: The table i generate will count entries created from 22/05/2021 03:00Z to 23/05/2021 02:59Z and display it under 23/05/2021. Kindly advice using moment.js.

Comment: doing the following allows me to calculate as required. However, the header date shows 1 day lesser due to the subtraction. 
var date = moment(item.Created).subtract(7, 'hours').format("DD/MM/YYYY");

Comment: In this case you would need to add 9 hours to the date `var date = moment(item.Created).add(9, 'hours').format("DD/MM/YYYY");` so it would count to the correct date

Comment: Kindly advice the need to sub 9? I subtract 7 for timezone reasons. Possible to show date range in the header of the table? example 22-23/05/2021

Comment: If you want to have the dates from e.g. 22/05/2021 3:00 to 23/05/2021 2:59 mapped to 23/05/2021 you need to **add** 21 hours (my mistake, sorry) to the date, so 22/05/2021 3:00 would become 23/05/2021 0:00 and 23/05/2021 2:59 would become 23/05/2021 23:59. So both of them are mapped to 23/05/2021. If you would want to add the range to the header you could just append the previous day as string.

Comment: Thankyou. Appreciate the help!